# Make [casperjs], [phantomjs] and [spookyjs] tags default to [javascript] code highlighting

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like see the default syntax highlighting for questions regarding [casperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/casperjs), [phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phantomjs) and [spookyjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spookyjs) tags to that of javascript. Right now, nothing is highlighted.

Most of the questions asked are in javascript. Very few people ask questions with coffeescript in those tags.

Of course there are also questions in [phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phantomjs) that use [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and many more, but the questions are explicitly tagged with those and should supercede the highlighting of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

Can this be done and how?

Comment: There is no way to have one tag supersede another when it comes to highlighting.